# Upload single text file using php and html and traverse to find repeated words

Tags: php, html

I wanted to write a code which will let me upload a text file and then find the words repeated inside the file but my program is not even printing the lines. What to do?

This is upload.php file which will be reading and verifying the file received.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "text/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$fileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists."."<br>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large."."<br>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($fileType != "txt" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only txt files are allowed."."<br>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded."."<br>";
}
else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        $lines = file("$target_file");
        foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
          echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

This is index.php file from which I am sending the file as POST request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/use.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Upload a file for word matching</h2>
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what output are you actually getting from this, is it `Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.`? The second parameter for `move_uploaded_file` needs to include a file name as well, but you used `$target_dir`, which only points to a directory, so this should fail.

Comment: @04FS My output from this code is `The file readme.txt has been uploaded`. After changing the `$targer_dir` inside of `move_uploaded_file` to `$target_file` it is showing `Sorry, there was an error uploading you file`.

Comment: That makes no sense, it should be exactly the other way around. Is this the actual code you are using? Sounds like it might not be. But assuming `$target_dir` contains a valid path/filename combination, then `$lines = file($target_dir);` should work …?

Comment: @04FS That's what is confusing me that it should be `$target_file` and I verified from all sites only my code is working the opposite way. Yes, this is the exact same code I'm running now and no, `$lines = file($target_dir);` is not working.